# How to speed up the search function of datatables?

Tags: mysqli, datatables

here's my code to search in tables (datatables):
Total records: 333,213
Estimated time to search/appear the result: 5 to 10 seconds.

```
using :  ajax: "sample.php", // json datasource
```

how to make it fast? 
what should I fix the database or the code I'm using.

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
include ('connectvl.php');
/* Database connection end */

// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0=> 'id',
    1=> 'FULLNAME',
    2=> 'BrgyName',
    3=> 'BDAY',
   4=> 'RESSTREET'


);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT id";
$sql.=" FROM voterslist2012";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("cswd_listofpendingprocessgrid.php: get employees");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql = "SELECT id, FULLNAME, BrgyName, BDAY, RESSTREET";
$sql.=" FROM voterslist2012 WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
    $sql.=" AND ( id LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";   
  $sql.=" OR FULLNAME LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' "; 
  $sql.=" OR BDAY LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' "; 
  $sql.=" OR BrgyName LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";

}

    // If there is a search parameter
/*if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string(
       $conn,
       // Match beginning of word boundary
       "[[:<:]]".
       // Replace space characters with regular expression
       // to match one or more space characters in the target field
       implode("[[.space.]]+",             
          preg_split("/\s+/", 
             // Quote regular expression characters
             preg_quote(trim($requestData['search']['value']))
          )
       ).
       // Match end of word boundary
       "[[:>:]]"
    );


    $sql.=" AND ( id REGEXP '$search' ";    
    $sql.=" OR FULLNAME REGEXP '$search' ";
    $sql.=" OR BrgyName REGEXP '$search' ";
     $sql.=" OR BDAY REGEXP '$search' ";
    $sql.=" OR RESSTREET REGEXP '$search' )";
}*/

$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("cswd_listofpendingprocessgrid.php: get employees");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */    
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("cswd_listofpendingprocessgrid.php: get employees");
$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 
   $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["FULLNAME"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["BDAY"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["BrgyName"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["RESSTREET"];
   $data[] = $nestedData;
}
$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIKE` in your `WHERE` clause is always going to be dead slow, since it bypasses any indexes present and uses a full table scan. I'm going to leave the issue of prepared statements vs. dynamic SQL for others to raise (You should be using prepared statements. ;) ), but if you make `id` your primary key and then do an *exact* match in your `WHERE` clause, the difference will bloody well astound you.

EDIT: If practicable, you should consider placing indexes on any fields you search frequently. Your `BDAY` column would be a good candidate. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL's optimizer to say if indexing `FULLNAME` or `BRGYNAME` be a good idea, but you could experiment.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the wildcard is at the end of the search string (which it is in this case), then it should still be able to take advantage of the index for that column.

Comment: @Lock: a) good point, and b) since the `WHERE` conjunction is `OR`, we're still going to have to do a full table scan if the index scan fails to match.

Comment: meaning sir reducing or removing a column(brgyname) search will help to optimize the search function?

Comment: Another good point. If you don't have a search criterion for a particular column it should not be mentioned at all in the `WHERE` clause. This will take more PHP code to accomplish, but should improve performance and reduce the risk of unexpected behaviour from your search.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax thanks. I will reduce the field and let see hope to reduce the time.